# Where do you get the latest nginx-extras? 1.16.1 is old?

Tags: apt, server, package-management, updates, nginx

Where do you get the latest nginx-extras? 1.16.1 is old?!

What I have (on Ubuntu 18.04):

`/etc/apt/sources.list.d/nginx-ubuntu-stable-bionic.list`

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/nginx/stable/ubuntu bionic main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/nginx/stable/ubuntu bionic main
```

```
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt dist-upgrade
$ nginx -v
nginx version: nginx/1.16.1
```

I tried commenting the "custom launchpad repo". Nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maintainer of the NGINX PPA repository here!

It's pending being copied into the stable repository.  Got some build errors hitting the builders that have prevented me copying a newer into the stable repos.  I'm working on a fix for that in those repos.

Patience please, I've got a lot of obligations outside of Ubuntu to get through ;)

Note that **the repository in question only supports current releases of Ubuntu, with the exception of Xenial 16.04.**

**EDIT** Looks like my workflow/workers that handle the initial testing forgot to mention they didn't fail so it's been sitting waiting for me to act for a while since July.  The packages are copying from the [Staging PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Eteward/+archive/ubuntu/nginx-stable-testing/+packages) to the main NGINX PPA and that can take up to an hour to be reflected.

Comment: Niiccee! Do I have to upgrade from Ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04?

Comment: @uav no.  Not until 2023, or until it becomes impossible for me to maintain NGINX for Bionic (the libs in Xenial are so old that it makes it very hard to maintain NGINX compatibility there, so it's not receiving PPA updates anymore from the NGINX PPAs)

Comment: Thank you! `nginx version: nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu)`

Comment: Hello again, when will 1.19.3 be available? I need it because of http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_cookie_flags - Tell me how I can support you - if you like.

Comment: @uav It'll get handled when I get a spare minute.  I've got a lot of things on my list right now to handle, not just for my nginx volunteering.

Comment: Dude! When will https://ubuntu.com/security/notices/USN-4967-1 and https://ubuntu.com/security/notices/USN-4967-2 be fixed?

Comment: @uav have you *read* the USNs?  Updates are already in the repositories for those issues.  USNs only are written when releases to updates and the `-security` pockets are made.